# Not able to find a list of dates in another list of dates - vba

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

What I am trying to do:

> Search list of dates from `col I` in another list of dates in `col B` if yes then do something.

[image]

This seems easy to do and I have tried a lot using different methods but not able to quite detect it for some reason.

Here is the [Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/runxic6azi42uvt/Ratio_Finder_Rev1.xlsm?dl=0)  if you want to have a look at the formats and how data is formatted etc.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RatioFinder()

'Variable Declarations
Dim wk, ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j, l, m, n, p, q As Long
Dim sdate, edate, df, ndate, ckdate, midate As Date
Dim st, ITol, STol, ETol As Variant
Dim win As Variant
Dim FRow, FRowO As Long
Dim rt As Double

'Setting Worksheet Variables
Set wk = Sheet1
Set ws = Sheet3

wk.Range("I2:Z1048576").Clear

'Finding LastRows
FRow = wk.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row       'Total No. of dates
FRowO = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row      'For Ouput Sheet

'Total No. of Ratios
win = wk.Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1

'Tolerance Values
ITol = wk.Range("G2").Value  'Except the start Date and End Date Match with using this Tolerance
STol = wk.Range("G3").Value  'This is for Start Date only can be negative
ETol = wk.Range("G4").Value  'This is for End Date only can be negative

'First loop is to loop through the Date Col "B" and get every combination of start and End date.
'First it takes one date as start date and Every other date as End Date

Dim ct, z As Long

n = 2
z = 2
ct = 0

For i = 2 To FRow - 1
        sdate = wk.Range("B" & i).Value            'Get Start Date

        For j = i + 1 To FRow
        edate = wk.Range("B" & j).Value            'Get End Date
        df = edate - sdate                         'Get Difference

                If df >= win Then                     'Check if enough dates are available

                    'Calculate Ratios
                    For m = 2 To (win + 1)

                        rt = wk.Range("D" & m).Value        'Ratio
                        ndate = Round(Round(df * rt) + sdate)      'NewDate According to Ratio
                        wk.Range("I" & n).Value = ndate     'Print New Date
                        wk.Range("J" & n).Value = rt        'Print Ratio
                        wk.Range("K" & n).Value = sdate     'Print Start Date
                        wk.Range("L" & n).Value = edate     'Print End date
                        wk.Range("M" & n).Value = df        'Print Difference
                        n = n + 1

                    Next m
```

> From here the code starts to check if all the dates except the start and end date were found or not.
>   Example : after the macro is finished you will see that all the dates from col I are there in col B but it fails to detect don't know why.

```
                           'This is to check whether all the dates are present in the list or not
                            For p = 3 To win    'win is 8 here
                            ckdate = wk.Range("I" & p).Value  'Get Date to Check

                                For q = 2 To FRow
                                    midate = wk.Range("B" & q).Value
                                    If ckdate >= (midate - ITol) And ckdate <= (midate + ITol) Then
                                        ct = ct + 1
                                    Else: End If
                                Next q

                            Next p

                            'Check if All the Internal Dates were found or not
                            If ct >= (win - 2) Then
                                wk.Range("O" & z) = ct
                                wk.Range("P" & z) = sdate
                                wk.Range("Q" & z) = edate
                                z = z + 1
                            Else: End If

                Else: End If
                n = 2
                ct = 0

        Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Any other way to do what I am trying to do ?

What I am trying to do:

> Search list of dates from `col I` in another list of dates in `col B` if yes then do something.

Comment: Try changing variables to doubles and use `.Value2` instead, If that does not work change it to a string and use `.Text`

Comment: okay thanks I will try that now

Comment: @ScottCraner `.Text` won't be suitable here since I want to subtract and add days to dates so storing them as text won't work and `Value2` doesn't seems to work as well

Answer (score 0):

Use DateSerial.

```
Dim lngDate1 as long
Dim lngDate2 as long


lngDate1 = DateSerial(Year(dte1), Month(dte1), Day(dte1))
lngDate2 = DateSerial(Year(dte2), Month(dte2), Day(dte2))

If lngDate1 = lngDate2 then do something
```

Comment: but isn't the format of dates are same so I think this is unnecessary isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not the issue but could potentially cause problems, edate is actually a vba function so may want to change the variable name for that one.